# Why does connecting my iPhone to iTunes causes my Acer laptop to crash?

Tags: laptop, iphone, itunes, bsod

I have an Acer Travelmate 8200 laptop and whenever I connect my iPhone to it, it crashes with a BSOD (Blue Screen Of Death).

I have figured out that if I delete all the pictures in my phone I can get it to connect but that is not an ideal long-term solution.

I also read that it may be a conflict with the built in web-cam I have but I've upgraded the driver and I still get the crashing problem.

---

Here is the BSOD message I get:

[image]

Comment: You need to give the specific model of the computer as well as the exact message that the BSOD gives.

Comment: What worked for me was upgrading to windows 7...  after that I haven't had a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try update USB or chipset drivers for your notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Paul, have you tried [disabling AutoRun](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/disable-autoplay-of-audio-cds-and-usb-drives/)? Try that, then plug your iPhone in and see if your notebook still crashes. It might be related to something trying to automatically import your photos.

Comment: Yes, I tried disabling autorun but it still crashes.   Just before the crash the phone connects as 'Digital Still Camera'.