# My computer blue screens when I connect my iPhone

Tags: windows-xp, bsod, iphone

New iPhone - all synced ok with itunes when first connected. Once I had taken some pictures I get [the blue sceen](https://superuser.com/questions/3273/connecting-my-iphone-to-itunes-causes-my-acer-laptop-to-crash) I am using Windows XP.

I have tried it on another computer using Windows 7 and it doesn't crash, but this isn't mine.
Is upgrading to Windows 7 my only option?

Answer (score 1):

> iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch: Windows displays a blue screen message or restarts when connecting your device

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1502

If your PC has a camera attached other than the iphone (usually a logitech) try disabling it or uninstalling the driver for it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a driver issue.

Im not sure what kind of drivers the iphone uses, but you should completely remove any that are there and reinstall them

http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1538